# How to ensure that paths for executables are added to path for Adobe AIR application?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I wok on desktop Adobe AIR application. It creates .DMG for mac os builds. It is actually command line application. What I want is the ability to call it from command line  - add it .../*.app/Content/MacOS to $PATH. Is there any standard way to do it with AIR ? I need it to work on Windows as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No standard way, that's for sure. It's out of scope of AIR. You probably should do that with the shell - something like SET %PATH% = %PATH% + ... Assuming your AIR application has access to shell interpreter, it can do it on first run right after install.